# Jest testing react-router-dom Link click

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, jestjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to capture in jest the click on a Link

```
<Link to="/exchange">Exchange</Link>
```

```
const comp = mount(
      <Router>
        <ComponentWithLink {...state} />
      </Router>
    );

const link = comp.find("Link");
    link.simulate("click");

// What do I test ?
```

I've tried to figure out how to add a mock without getting anywhere. I have a feeling I need to check location or mock the react-router-dom module, but I'm not getting any luck.

Anybody can point me in the right direction ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't test dom operations in jest. if you trying to test the click on link then this tests already ready inside library.

If you want to test props in some link then do that:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MemoryRouter><MyComponent/></MemoryRouter>);
expect(wrapper.find(Link).at(0).props().to).toBe('/my-route');
```

Comment: Interesting, so the thought process is that if I unit test that the prop is set correctly, then, combined with the unit tests of Link, it covers that it should navigate to /my-route

I was approaching it from a integration test point of view, my component has a Link, when I click on it, X should happen